# Volume tag description

Tags: discussion

I just rejected a tag edit for "volume". Obviously this term is ambigeous so the tag should get a description now but a look at the questions with this tag showed me that most questions use it in the sense of `filesystem volume`, not in the sense of `sound volume`.

Thus I suggest to use it for filesystems.

Of course, there should be an additional tag for sound volume. But as I am not a native speaker I do not create that myself now but ask more qualified people to make suggestions.

Comment: Off the cuff, I wonder if the [tag:audio] tag covers volume.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Indeed, maybe there is just not enough demand for a tag specific to the volume aspect.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty clear case of a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). I'd be more inclined to delete the tag entirely.

Comment: @terdon I have read the linked article and my assessment is that those arguments affect neither meaning of volume. But `volume` may be completely covered by the tag `filesystems`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging the point is that `volume` alone is too ambiguous, so isn't a good tag. As you correctly point out, it can be used for audio volume or filesystem volume, that's why I don't think it's a useful tag at all. If we want a tag for filesystem volumes, then I think `filesystem-volume` would be a better choice.

Comment: I really don't see any point in having a tag for either of those. They are perfectly covered by their filesystem (xfs, btrfs, ext, etc.) and audio manager tags (pulseaudio, alsa, jack(?)).

Answer (score 7):

I would argue that [volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volume) is a textbook example of a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

> 2. If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag. In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag [subjective] itself … is actually subjective. Ditto for [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? These tags are impossible to define by anything remotely resembling an objective metric. In comparison, the the meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and [javascript] are crystal clear to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

It can mean different things to different people and I can't imagine how it could help experts find questions. Surely nobody is an expert on [volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volume) who isn't an expert on [audio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio). And the multiple meanings of *volume* make it impossible to know if the tag would refer to a filesystem volume or audio volume or something else.

I would therefore suggest burminating [volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volume) and replacing it with [filesystem-volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filesystem-volume) and, if needed [audio-volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-volume) although I think the latter is better served with [audio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio).

Comment: I agree with the renaming of `volume` to `filesystem-volume` as it appears if you type `volume`. Should not be a problem and just improve the sutiation. As `audio` is an "ignore tag" for me I do not have an opinion whether `audio-volume` would be justified beside `audio`. In general I would argue that it is precise and does not hurt, thus in case of doubt I would rather have it than not.

Comment: 1) I'm not sure whether it's safe to assume that "fileystem" applies to any [tag:storage-volume] - e.g. an LVM volume used as swap space. (Right offhand I'm not sure [tag:storage-volume] would be safe either). 2) Wouldn't [tag:audio-volume] as a synonym for [tag:audio] be useful to nudge question askers towards an existing tag and reduce the odds of [tag:volume] being re-created?

Comment: I have created `audio-volume` and changed the tag in the audio questions. I prefer fra-san's `storage-volume` over `filesystem-volume`. I guess only a moderator can rename a tag. I was just a bit surprised that there is a tag `storage` which includes RAM...

Comment: Should there be an alias to [audio-volume] with the name [sound-volume]?

Comment: @fra-san 1) yes, good point. I guess `storage-volume` is a better choice. 2) again, good point, a synonym does make sense.

Comment: I agree with most of this answer (blacklisting [tag:volume] based on ambiguity). I don't know off-hand if we have a tag "vacuum" for filesystems or audio; we already have quite a few tags...